# How to use href to pass url id to multiple php file?

Tags: php

I am trying to use chatrooms.php to choose chatroom to enter and both the chatroom have one id For example chat room 1 id = 1 and chat room 2 id=2 and now i want to use chatrooms.php to href into chatroom which the chatoom is select by user and chatroom.php have 2 php file for function whihc are

- chatMessage.php -this is use for load message - with js ajax polling
- chat.php - this is use for insert chat

[This is the chatrooms.php let user to select the chat rooms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAynu.png)

[Once you select chat room the url id will change based on what chat room you choose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkzzV.png)

I was doing a multiple chat room it will only load what chat room your are in

Here is chatrooms.php:

```
    <table class="table table-hover">
    <?php
    include '../config.php';
    $sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM chatroom");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="chatRoom.php?chatroomID=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
                <div>
                    <p>
                        <?php echo ($row['name']); ?>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
    } 
    ?>
</table>
```

Here is chat.php:

```
<?php 

include '../config.php';
include'login.php';

$userID = $_SESSION['id'];
$message = $_GET['message'];
$chatroomID =$_GET['chatroomID'];

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
mysqli_query ($connection,"delete from chat where date < DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 1 MONTH)");

$sql = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO chat(`user_id`, `chat`,`date`)VALUES('$userID', '$message','$today')")or die(mysqli_error($connection));
$chatID=  mysqli_insert_id($connection);
$sql2 = mysqli_query($connection,"INSERT INTO chatroom_chat(chatroom_id,chat_id)VALUES('$chatroomID','$chatID')")or die(mysqli_error($connection));



$sql1= "SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT * FROM chat ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,40
            ) sub
            ORDER BY id ASC ";

$result =  mysqli_query($connection, $sql1);

$sql3 = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '$userID'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql3)) {
    while($extract = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $color = ($row['username'] == $_SESSION['username']) ? '#FFFFFF' : '#66FFFF';
        $position = ($row['username'] == $_SESSION['username']) ? 'right' : 'left';
        $border = ($row['username'] == $_SESSION['username']) ? ' 1px solid black ' : ' none ';

        echo "<div class='msg-dateandtime' style='text-align:$position; float:$position;'> <div class='left-username' style='color:blue;'>" . $row['username'] ."</div>"
                . "<div class='space'></div>"
                . "<div class='right-date'>  ". $extract['date'] ." </div></div>"
                . "<div class='wrap-message' style='background-color:$color; border:$border; float:$position;'>"
                . "<p style 'text-align=$position; margin:0; padding:0; text-align:left;'> ".$extract['chat']."</p></div>";
    }
}
?>
```

here is chatMessage.php:

```
<?php 
        include '../config.php';
        include 'login.php';


        $userID = $_SESSION['id'];
        $chatroomID =$_GET['chatroomID'];

        $sql="SELECT * FROM chatroom_chat where chatroom_id ='$chatroomID'";
        $result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
            $chat = $row['chat_id'];
            $getChatData = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM chat WHERE id = '$chat' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,40)sub ORDER BY id ASC");

                while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($getChatData)) {
                    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
                    $color = ($username == $_SESSION['username']) ? '#FFFFFF' : '#66FFFF';
                    $position = ($username == $_SESSION['username']) ? 'right' : 'left';
                    $border = ($username == $_SESSION['username']) ? ' 1px solid black ' : ' none ';

                    echo "<div class='msg-dateandtime' style='text-align:$position; float:$position;'> <div class='left-username' style='color:blue;'>" .$username."</div>"
                            . "<div class='space'></div>"
                            . "<div class='right-date'>  ". $row3['date'] ." </div></div>"
                            . "<div class='wrap-message' style='background-color:$color; border:$border; float:$position;'>"
                            . "<p style 'text-align=$position; margin:0; padding:0; text-align:left;'> ".$row3['chat']."</p></div>";
                }

        }
    ?>
```

And the chatRoom.php is only html code.
My problem is i cant get the chatroomID from the href to chatMessage.php and chat.php

Comment: I didn't really take a look at your code so I don't know exactly what you want to do but I guess you should do `include 'chat.php'` and `include 'chatMessage.php'` in `chatRoom.php`

Comment: what i want is i have 2 chatroom with id = 1 and id =2 i want to pass the chat room id into chat.php and chatMessage.php

Comment: So you would have to do like I said. You can point the link to one php file but in that php file you have to use `include` to get the other files. Just like what you did for `login.php` and `config.php`

Comment: i have edited the question. maybe will be more clear